# Web API Exchange.WebServices Library

Tags: c#, web-services, web, asp.net-web-api, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get an MVC4 WebApi to use the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices library, but for some reason it is not connecting to the remote server, instead it looks like it's connecting to the loopback address.

The weird thing is that the exact same code works if used in a console application.

I encapsulated the problem in this simple block of code:

```
Folder exchangeFolder = null;

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Timeout = 600000;
service.Url = new Uri("https://HOSTNAME/exchange.asmx");

service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DOMAIN");

FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));

foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults)
{
    if ("inbox".Equals(folder.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        exchangeFolder = folder;
        break;
    }
}

int inboxItemCount = exchangeFolder.TotalCount;
```

The innermost exception gives me the following details:

```
{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6699"}
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

The code fails with the same exception in both, ASP.NET applications and MVC4 WebApi applications, but works on Console applications.

Is it possible for those types of applications to use the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices library? 
If so, what else needs to be configured to get it working?

Comment: Is your IIS on the same machine as console app?

Comment: That is correct, same machine.

Comment: Can you go to project's properties in VS, click Web on left side, and check under Servers - what is the port number?

Comment: For my ASP.NET test application, the port is: 49474.
For my MVC4 WebApi application, the port is: 52771.
And for my original application, which is a mix of both, the port is:59435.
 
They all throw the same exception with the same port in the exception message ("...refused it 127.0.0.1:6699").5:10 PM
Maybe the fact that they are all from different ports and throwing the same exception (with the same port on the exception) will shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

you need the reference using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

it can be installed by the nuget package Microsoft exchange webserivices

make sure the dll deploys with your code to the host server